# Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: Illegal Capacity: -873101876

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

im using android studio 3.0 and when i start build project i have this

```
Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Cause:
Illegal Capacity: -873101876
```

why this happened?

Comment: Does this also happen if you run gradle from the commandline? What does the Gradle Log tool window of AS show?